# Gitlab Omnibus, can't view most commits (500) and very slow

Tags: nginx, git, ubuntu-14.04, 500-error, gitlab

I'm running GitLab 7.9.2 c46d4f5 (Omnibus) on Ubuntu 14.04

On a little over half of our commits when someone navigates to a commit gitlab returns

*500 We're sorry, but something went wrong*

Also, on commits that don't return 500, they take anywhere from 5 to 20 seconds to show the page. I'm watching all of the logs as this is happening, and nothing that stands out as an obvious problem is happening.

When i go to a commit that returns a 500 error, the nginx logs return:

```
192.168.1.x - - [27/May/2015:09:35:44 -0500] "GET /project/module/commit/6876452e1df1d2846dhd1b2eb7d907e6ae8hf7d5 HTTP/1.1" 500 349 "https://gitlab.company.com/project/module/commits/staging" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36"
```

Something else that's been happening, that I'm not sure if it's normal or not is that every 3 to 5 seconds in the nginx logs I get:

```
192.168.1.y - - [27/May/2015:09:40:06 -0500] "POST //api/v1/builds/register.json HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "-"
```

192.168.1.y is a gitlab ci runner, and I assumed that the 3-5 seconds of contact was some form of keep alive, but I definitely don't know.

Any help is appreciated, none of the other logs are showing any errors, or anything odd. I've checked unicorn, sidekiq, nginx, and postgresql.

As a side note, I can still access all of the stats that the UI provided via terminal, but I have a lot of users who prefer using the UI.

Another side note, is that this is a VM running on Hyper-v 2012, and the linux tools have been installed from [these](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531029.aspx) instructions.  Having said that, I really don't think it's an issue with anything other than gitlab.